# Is it possible to force PHP code to continue running, if a php.ini directive such as upload_max_filesize is exceeded when uploaded file exceeds this?

Tags: php, directive

I have a single PHP page, with the php (v7.4.7) script at the top of the page. The page functions as a file up-loader, allows up to 10 files per upload, and the max file size is set in the script.
The site works perfectly, generating a table of the result of each file to the user.

That is, unless someone uploads a file greater than the **upload_max_filesize** directive in the php.ini file. At which point, the script stops dead and cannot therefore, continue to provide the necessary results back to the user. No results are returned, the results table is therefore empty, and the user might think, wrongly, all went well.

I have tried adding try/catch blocks, but the script still fails to complete. Is this by design, or is there a way to coerce the script to run/complete, if this directive is exceeded? The HTML/PHP code is all pretty standard, as demonstrated by various tutorials etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure PHP shouldn't stop processing entirely if that size is exceeded. [The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) suggests that the `$_FILES` array entry for that file will just be populated with an error, definitely not that the script execution is halted. Is there anything useful in your error log?

Comment: Assuming the user that should receive some results is not a malicious user, although it doesn't solve the root of the problem, have you considered limiting the file size on the client's end?

Comment: _“I have tried adding try/catch blocks”_ - try/catch works for _exceptions_. A file not making it past the upload limit, does not throw any exceptions to begin with.

Comment: Re client side file size limiting - I assume that this can be changed by the end user, so thought it better to just handle it server-side. The php error log has entries such as: "PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 214026758 bytes exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes in Unknown on line 0", but the script never completes when this happens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Violating `upload_max_filesize` doesn't abort the script execution. It'll just cause the `error` key in `$_FILES` to become `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`.

Most likely, you're hitting an entirely different limit. For example, Apache has
`LimitRequestBody` and PHP itself has `post_max_size` or even `max_file_uploads`. In general, those directives don't abort the script either but simply wipe out the data excess.

My advice is to locate all the directives that may affect file uploads, set them one by one to an artificially low limit and verify what effect they have in your data. A check I typically do is to verify if `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` is greater than zero for a request where `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is `POST` but `$_POST` is empty. Aside that, checking `error` in `$_FILES` should have you fairly covered.

---

```
; Allow enough time for the upload to complete
max_input_time = 1200
; Max file size
upload_max_filesize = 50M
; Greater than upload_max_filesize to ease diagnose slightly large files
post_max_size = 100M
```

```php
if (
    empty($_FILES) &&
    empty($_POST) &&
    isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) &&
    strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])=='post'
) {
    // Error: post body was too large
    // Bytes sent (and discarded): filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'CONTENT_LENGTH')
} elseif (
    isset($_FILES['foo']) &&
    $_FILES['foo']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
){
    // Upload
    if ($_FILES['foo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        // Successful upload
    }else{
        // Failed upload
    }
} else {
    // No upload
}
```

Comment: Álvaro González - Thanks for highlight the above directives, and thanks to all for your comments!

After changing the various directives in cPanel's MultiPHP INI Editor, the culprit is post_max_size. If the file size is larger than the setting for this directive, the php script does NOT complete and return any results I have programmed back to the client browser!!

I presume there is no workaround for this!?

Many thanks again to ALL!

Comment: Sorry if my answer was unclear. Exceeding `post_max_size` doesn't abort the script or prevent it from running. Seriously. And I've included a code sample you can basically copy and paste, although you need to tweak it for your exact form structure (your field is not called `foo`, is it?). If your script doesn't complete, it must be something you've coded yourself.

Comment: I'm very new to php programming, so please excuse my inexperience. The script runs perfectly - supplying all the Success/Failed results per included file to the browser, but only when the post_max_size is not breached by any one file. This is my very first post on Stack Overflow, is it too late to post my code to the initial question? Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to substantially change a question that already has an accepted answer, perhaps it's better to just ask a new question. But I suggest you first double check what lines of code execute and which don't—is PHP completely failing to run?

Comment: When you say I'm "substantially" changing the question - is this because I suggested subsequently adding the code? I have placed echo statements, with echo "1," just before the "if(isset($_POST['submit'])){" statement, and the rest after each block of statements (if(), for() etc). So, for a single file which should, and does succeed, the app prints 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13, The missing numbers are the code blocks for checking for errors - which there were none. However, when I run the app on a file with size greater than  post_max_size, only '1' is returned to the browser. Hope this helps!

Comment: The question being asked here is how to force PHP to continue running when when upload_max_filesize is exceeded and I answered that's the default behaviour. I understand my answer doesn't solve your problem because the diagnostic that lead to the question wasn't fully correct. That's fine, just hit the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and share your code there.